# Split polygon in smaller and equal poylgon

Tags: qgis, python, polygon, grass-gis, splitting

I need to split polygon features as in the figure.[image]

Is there any automatic tool for this?

Comment: What do you mean with equal? If you have area of 101 square something would you like to get 10 times 10.1, or 10 times 10 + one or more smaller polygons?

Comment: I mean that if I have rectagnle of 100*50 I want to drow inside 50 polygons of 10*5 for example.

Comment: If you want to have an automatic tool then I fear that your definition "50 polygons of 10*5 for example" is not exact enough. Should the result be triangles, rectangles or something else? Oriented north-south along some axis (which axes?). What to do if you have a circle shaped polygon as an input geometry etc? Because it is not at all trivial it may be that such tool does not exist yet but I do not know really.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 3):

The closest automatic solution I can think of is the [Polygon Divider](https://github.com/jonnyhuck/RFCL-PolygonDivider) plugin.

However, if you want the result to be exactly like your image, you will need to write your own.  I'd recommend a Python script where you iterate over each polygon in the shapefile, find its major axis, orientation and dimensions and then calculate the subdivisions.